# Display a timer for an iOS app that persists between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I've been trying to get a timer to show at the bottom left corner of my app by using an `NSTimer`, and making the "elapsed time" show as `UILabel` on the bottom left corner but it hasn't been working for me.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(aTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)aTime
{
    NSLog(@"....Update Function Called....");

    static int i = 1;

    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

    i++;
}
```

The timer actually works but I can't get it to be triggered by a button. I'm trying to get the timer to continue and not restart at 1 when it enters to the next storyboard/xib file.

Comment: Can you please include your code so that we may look at it to determine why it is not working?

Comment: Sorry for that. I was experimenting with different codes trying to see if I could make things work so I didn't really have a code to post a while back cause they were kind of just drafts. But I posted the code I'm using now. Hope that helps! Thanks.

Comment: @user1677210: now what is the issue ? Timer is not working or need to implement it in button click ?

Comment: If you want it triggered by a button, then put the timer creation code in the button method, not viewDidLoad.

Comment: @MidhunMP the only issue now is how do I get the Timer to continue on even after going to another storyboard/xib. Like if it ends at 10 on the first storyboard/xib file it should continue to 11 at the next.

Answer (score 11):

For implementing the timer action on the button press, you need to write it on a `IBAction` method like:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPress
{
    NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(aTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

For storing the previous value, you can use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or a SQLite database. For this purpose I'll suggest `NSUserDefaults`.

Change the aTime method like:

```
-(void)aTime
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    id obj = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"TimerValue"];
    int i = 0;

    if(obj != nil)
    {
        i = [obj intValue];
    }

    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    i++;

    [standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"TimerValue"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Do I just put this method on the first view controller? or should I put it as well to the other succeeding view controllers?

Comment: No, just replace your aTime in first view controller

Comment: But then when I would switch to the next view the label with the time would disappear

Comment: wherever you are using the same timer for displaying the time, you need to use this

Comment: Alright I did just that but when it moves to the next view the timer stops let's say if the last view lasted for 5 seconds it would just show "5" at the next view.

Comment: I set the the method on the next view right after -(void)viewDidLoad{

Comment: then you need to set the timer again, because when you move to another view, the timer is getting released and set to nil. That's why it displays a constant value.

Comment: Oh so with this method I can't have the timer continue counting time on the next view? So I would really need a singleton to do this?

Comment: ya, or use the timer on other thread. and don't release or don't  set to nil in the first view. :)

Comment: Ohh Alright man thanks :) But isn't the releasing automatic with Xcode 4 cause of ARC?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the method `aTime` is in your view controller, when you enters another view, this view controller is released and you can't perform selector aTime anymore.

so I suggest that you put your `aTime` method and `i` to a singleton(or any object that won't be released when you enter another view) and set the singleton as the target of your timer.

also you should keep code below in your view controller so that you can update your label properly when you came back to this view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(aTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)aTime
{
    NSLog(@"....Update Function Called....");

    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",theSingleton.i];
}
```

**better choice:**

You can declare i as a property of your singleton, and then add an observer to i, then you'll get your label updated on time.
call -startTimer when you want to count time.

the singleton:

```
  @interface Singleton

  @property (nonatomic,retain) NSNumber *i;

  @end

  @implementation

+(Singleton*)instance
{
    //the singleton code here
}

-(void)startTimer
{
    NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(aTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)aTime
{
    NSInteger temp = [i integerValue];
    temp ++;
    self.i = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp];
}
```

the view controller:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[Singleton instance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"i" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL]];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"....Update Function Called....");

    Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Singleton instance].i];
}
```

Comment: Thans for the help man. Singletons are pretty much new to me. I understand it in theory but I get lost a bit with the coding. How do I set up a Singleton for the time data?

Comment: You don't have to use a singleton then, you can just put i as a property in your application delegate.